# Sharing GPU memory in Android

Tags: android, gpu, shared-memory, vulkan

Is it possible to share GPU memory in Android (generic/textures/vertex buffers, etc) between processes?

The API to share CPU RAM was exposed in 8.1: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SharedMemory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HardwareBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/HardwareBuffer) objects can be passed between processes, and can be imported to/from Vulkan using the [VK_ANDROID_external_memory_android_hardware_buffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_ANDROID_external_memory_android_hardware_buffer) extension. You can use the functions in android/hardware_buffer_jni.h to move between Java/Kotlin (HardwareBuffer) and C++ (AHardwareBuffer) objects.